# Swagger (springfox) don't show an example from an openapi yaml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I'm using

1. org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.2.6-Release
2. swagger: io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0
3. plugin org.openapi.generator:6.0.1

I made a yaml file with OpenAPI description of my end-points.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: a
  description: a
  contact:
    name: a
    url: ''
    email: a@gmai.com
  version: 'Latest'
tags:
  - name: V1Api
    description: a
paths:
  '/v1/getSome':
    get:
      tags:
        - V1Api
      summary: summary
      operationId: getSome
      deprecated: false
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'OK'
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                description: a
                properties:
                  field_1:
                    description: field_1 description
                    type: boolean
                    example: true
                  field_2:
                    description: field_2 description
                    type: string
                    example: 'field_2 example'
              example:
                  field_1: false
                  field_2: 'field_2 overriden example'
```

[image: Without the example section. Only with examples for particular fields]
Pic1. Without the example section. Only with examples for particular fields

[image: With the example section. It overrides the fields examples]
Pic2. With the example section. It overrides the fields examples

I tried my yaml file in https://editor.swagger.io/ and got the desired swagger state. Swagger showed the example section ({field_1: false, field_2: 'field_2 overriden example'}) correctly. When I used the yaml in my project Swagger didn't show the example above. I check the code generated from the yaml. It didn't have that example.
I decided to check what code would be generated by https://editor.swagger.io/ if I choose "Generate Server -> spring". I didn't find the example there.

1. Why does the spring code generator ignore that example?
2. What should I do to make Swagger show that example?